# Webpack 5 Web-Worker has the wrong path after build. React 18, Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, web-worker, webpack-5

I recently upgraded my app to react 18 and it is going smoother than I thought.
I had to change how web workers worked with webpack 5 and I have followed the documentation.

```
const myWorker = new PromiseWorker(new Worker(new URL('../worker.ts', import.meta.url)));
```

This code works flawless in development.
but when I build my app and install it on my device.
The path to the web worker is incorrect and I'm not sure how I should workaround this.

#### Path it should have

`https://MyHost/blah/blah/resources/static/js/webworker.js`

#### Path it has in production

`https://MyHost/blah/blah/resources/static/js/static/js/webworker.js`

- Something to do with this import.meta.url?
- using electron-builder@23.0.3, react-scripts@5.0.1, react@18.2.0, electron@19.0.4
  I Want to fix it properly but I am open to working around it by creating the path in resources or forcing the path somehow

Comment: Should this be posted as an issue with react-scripts@5.0.1? I have made a quick workaround but it is dirty. I just Copy the /static/js into /static/js/static/js after react-scripts build. But I would love a solution that isn't a horrible practice like this.

Comment: I have the same issue. There is an open ticket for this with react-scripts here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12503