# Import module in WebWorker with Electron

Tags: electron, web-worker, webpack-5

In a React (CRA) application I have created a WebWorker that imports node_modules as well. When developing the application I can load the modules. But when I have build the application the modules in the WebWorker cannot be loaded. I have a file dependency in package.json, this dependency is used both by my API and the application and WebWorker.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "protobuf-js": "file:public/electron/protobuf-js"
  ...
}
```

As soon the WebWorker imports a file in the dependency that uses `require()` the error shown below is given when loading the WebWorker. Other dependencies such as *chart.js* can be loaded in the WebWorker.

Electron version: 27.1.3
Webpack version: 5.5.0

[image: Electron Chrome Dev errors]

Honestly, the weirdest thing in all this, is that it is working in development mode but not in the build application.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the version of your dependency, try changing it to an actual version (instead of file), reinstalling all the dependencies and building again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a duplicate of [Webpack 5 Web-Worker has the wrong path after build. React 18, Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634836/webpack-5-web-worker-has-the-wrong-path-after-build-react-18-electron), and this issue is also discussed on [Github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12503).